# Input FileUpload object in Java Script: can’t change the name of the selected file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, input, upload, rename

I’m trying to upload files using JS.

- My first step is to select the files to upload, this works fine.
- Then I checked if the file/s in the input tag are present

[image]

- With The following console command (using chrome version36.0.1985.125
  m) :

  `document.getElementById("InputfileSelection").files.item(1).name "image02.JPG"`

At this point everything works fine.
The only issue is that if I try to change the name of the file, it won’t work. How come?

```
document.getElementById("InputfileSelection").files.item(1).name="NEW NAME";
"NEW NAME"
```

The next step show that the **name hasn’t changed**:

```
document.getElementById("InputfileSelection").files.item(1).name
"image02.JPG"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not allow you to change anything on the filesystem of the client. It displays the filename for reference.

There is no point at renaming the file at that time anyways, rename it on your server once it is uploaded... Or open your file explorer and rename it there, but do not mix both.

Comment: Yep, guess I'll go for the server side, I just wanted to change the file name so that it would have been stored lower case and prevent extra work to the server. Just one more question, but after the files have be selected, are they stored in the browser or are they just referenced from the browser to the client's fileSystem?

Comment: They are referenced, once the form is submitted they are sent through the HTTP request. Uploaded files are put in a temporary folder, you need to move it to keep it, so you will need to rename no matter what.